# Seeding Identity roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have followed [this article](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17333/Custom-user-roles-and-rolebased-authorization-in-ASPNET-core/28352#.XogQZYj7S73) on how to seed roles to the database. It creates roles by calling a seeding-method from within a scope created in `Program.cs`, like so:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var serviceProvider = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
                var configuration = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                Seed.CreateRoles(serviceProvider, configuration).Wait();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(exception, "An error occurred while creating roles");
            }
        }

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

However, on this line: `using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())`, I'm getting a red squiggly on "host": "The name 'host' does not exist in the current context". How can I make it work in Asp.Net Core 3.1?

This is the seeding-method:

```
public static class Seed
{
    public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        //adding customs roles
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "HRManager", "User" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            // creating the roles and seeding them to the database
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        // creating a super user who could maintain the web app
        var poweruser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserEmail"],
            Email = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserEmail"]
        };

        string userPassword = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserPassword"];
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["UserEmail"]);

        if (user == null)
        {
            var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, userPassword);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                // here we assign the new user the "Admin" role 
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "SiteAdmin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I had somehow missed this line:

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);
```

But that didn't work anyway. I had to replace it with this:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
```

So now, `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var serviceProvider = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
                var configuration = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                Seed.CreateRoles(serviceProvider, configuration).Wait();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(exception, "An error occurred while creating roles");
            }
        }

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

And it works! :) Roles are written to the database.